# How to click on the element with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to click a the element with text as *I don't have the telephone* on this [website](https://passport.yandex.com/registration/mail?from=mail&require_hint=1&origin=hostroot_homer_reg_com&retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yandex.com%2F&backpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yandex.com%3Fnoretpath%3D1).

So I find the element with inspect. here is the element in html:

```
<span class="toggle-link link_has-no-phone" role="button">I&nbsp;don't have a&nbsp;telephone number</span>
```

In my nonfunctional code i wrote this:

```
r = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/main/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/span")
r.click
```

The button is never clicked and nothing happens i get no error and i can't click it any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `r.click()` instead of `r.click`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **I don't have a telephone number** you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.toggle-link.link_has-no-phone").click()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='toggle-link link_has-no-phone']").click()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selector below to get span:

```
r = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".link_has-no-phone")
r.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/main/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/span")
r.click()
```

You just forgot the parenthesis